# Dynamic output of category_description from custom taxonomy in Wordpress

Tags: custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm looking for a way of dynamically outputting the description of my categories in my custom post type's taxonomy, but I'm over my head in php in how to achieve it. I've read [the codex on category_description](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description) thorough but without any luck. Also I've looked at [this guide](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/08/how-to-build-a-media-site-on-wordpress-part-2/) from smashing mag.
Really hoping some php wizards can straighten me out

**It should look something like this on the multiple frontend displayed custom taxonomy categories**

```
<a href="#" title="category_description"></a>
```

**But it looks like this**

```
<a href="#" original-title></a>
```

**What I'm doing is this**

```
<?php echo '<li><a href="#" title="'.$presenter->description.'"</a></li>'; ?>
```

**I'm declaring the $presenter variable like this**

```
$presenter = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'portfolio' ) );
```

**And the $presenter variable is based on my custom post_type, which is declared like this**

```
register_post_type('portfolio', array( 'label' => 'Portfolio Items','description' => '','public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'show_in_menu' => true,'capability_type' => 'post','hierarchical' => false,'rewrite' => array('slug' => '%portfolio_page%','with_front'=>true),'query_var' => true,'supports' => array('title','editor','trackbacks','revisions','thumbnail'),'labels' => array (
                'name' => 'Portfolio Items',
                'singular_name' => 'Portfolio Item',
                'menu_name' => 'Portfolio Items',
                'add_new' => 'Add Portfolio Item',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Portfolio Item',
                'edit' => 'Edit',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Portfolio Item',
                'new_item' => 'New Portfolio Item',
                'view' => 'View Portfolio Item',
                'view_item' => 'View Portfolio Item',
                'search_items' => 'Search Portfolio Items',
                'not_found' => 'No Portfolio Items Found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Portfolio Items Found in Trash',
                'parent' => 'Parent Portfolio Item',
            ),) );
```

**And my custom taxonomy is declared like this**

```
function add_custom_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy('p_category', 'portfolio', array(
            'hierarchical' => true, 
            'labels' => array( 
                'name' => _x( 'Portfolio Category', 'taxonomy general name', 'theme_x' ), 
                'singular_name' => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name', 'theme_x' ), 
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Category', 'theme_x' ), 
                'all_items' => __( 'All Categories', 'theme_x' ),
                'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Category', 'theme_x' ), 
                'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:', 'theme_x' ), 
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category', 'theme_x' ), 
                'update_item' => __( 'Update Category', 'theme_x' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category', 'theme_x' ),
                'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category Name', 'theme_x' ), 
                'menu_name' => __( 'Portfolio Categories', 'theme_x' ), 
            ),
            'rewrite' => array( 
                'slug' => 'portfolio-category', 
                'with_front' => false, 
                'hierarchical' => true 
            ), 
        )
    );

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if this helps.

You really do not need to go in that much details. Simply echo out the function category_description(), this displays out the description of the custom taxonomy term. Just make sure you have description added for your Custom taxonomy term at yourwpurl.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=custom-taxonomy-slug